# Concurrent bulk adds in solr cloud environment

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud

Is it possible to improve bulk indexing speed by using a class similar to ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient in an solrcloud environment? (Using solrj)

On a local machine I could substantially improve initial indexing time when switching from using **SolrClient** to **ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient**.

For indexing on our cloud environment I am currently using **CloudSolrClient**, but indexing takes a long time.

Comment: If you are just indexing data, you can set high value for `autoCommit` and `autoSoftCommit` parameters in `solrconfig.xml`, which will improve the indexing speed. Once your bootstrap (mass indexing) process is completed, you can reset them to smaller values.

Comment: Thanks! The values for autoCommit and autoSoftCommit parameters are actually very high already. On a local machine I could substantially improve runtime by using ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient (55 minutes down to 2 minutes) . So I would like to perform a similar trick in my cloud setting...

Comment: Are you indexing data from your local machine and solr cloud is setup on some environment? If yes, what is the network latency between your local machine and solr cloud setup. My personal experience is, indexing 1.5GB in 5 min. We use the `CloudSolrServer` class from solrj.

Comment: Yes, I started using solr locally and later moved to our solr cloud. I am connected via 1000 megabit ethernet and the ping is around 20 ms. I assumed that the problem is that we bulk index very small text fragments. I am no expert to solr, but I thought that `CloudSolrServer` invokes a query for each document and waits for an `UpdateResponse`. So I thought `CloudSolrServer` mostly waits to open and close a network connection.